# Replying to people who answer my question

Tags: discussion

I'm sure there's a better place to ask this question but I do not know where it is when someone replies to one of my questions how do I reply to their answer? I am new to this forum and do not know the proper protocols so please forgive me.

Comment: Usually in comments. You need some small reputation to up/down vote or make comments.

Answer (score 4):

You are always able to leave comments on your own posts (questions or answers) **and** on answers to your questions. Once you reach 50 rep, you'll be able to leave [comments anywhere](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

However, looking at the site activity just now, I see two questions:

- [can I put 3 new light fixtures and switches on the same breaker](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/72275/can-i-put-3-new-light-fixtures-and-switches-on-the-same-breaker)
- [How many ceiling fans and switches can I put on one breaker](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/72279/how-many-ceiling-fans-and-switches-can-i-put-on-one-breaker)

Given that the identicons (the purple and white picture next to the user name underneath the questions) match, it appears that you have two user accounts; one guest account and one registered. Please consider [merging them](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), which will allow you to [edit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) on your questions.

If you run into any trouble with merging the accounts, leave a comment on this post and I (or one of the other moderators) will try to help you out.

Comment: I do not know how to retrieve the URL for my other account that I need to merge with your information is very helpful but I could not figure out how to do it

Comment: The URL of the other account is [`http://diy.stackexchange.com/users/41748/don-eanes`](http://diy.stackexchange.com/users/41748/don-eanes). Either copy from this comment or click through the link and copy it from the address bar in your browser.

Comment: They have that one on the help page I need the one for 41570 I believe

Comment: That would be [`http://diy.stackexchange.com/users/41750/user41750`](http://diy.stackexchange.com/users/41750/user41750). Note that the "Don Eanes" account is the unregistered one, so it's probably the (registered) "user41750" account that you should keep.